# Angular is missing resumeBootstrap function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently trying to setup a new AngularJS project using RequireJS. I have started with the [angularjs-requirejs-seed](https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed) project. I have done one project in the past using angular/require, but I have yet to be able to get it working with the "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP" way.

Here is my main.js file,

```
'use strict';

require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery",
        angular: "bower_components/angular/angular",
        angularRoute: "bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min",
        angularMocks: "bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.min",
        text: "bower_components/requirejs-text/text",
        compApp: "components/app",
    },
    shim: {
        'angular' : {'exports' : 'angular'},
        'angularRoute': ['angular'],
        'angularMocks': {
            deps:['angular'],
            'exports':'angular.mock'
        }
    },
    priority: [
        "angular"
    ]
});

//http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/docs/guide/bootstrap#overview_deferred-bootstrap
window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!";

require([
    'angular',
    'compApp/app'
], function(angular, app) {
    var $html = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);

    angular.element().ready(function() {
        angular.resumeBootstrap([app['name']]);
    });
});
```

When I run this I get an error `undefined is not a function` on the resumeBoostrap line. When I debug the app and set a breakpoint on the resumeBootstrap line, I find that angular is missing the resumeBootstrap method. However the window.name is showing NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP properly. Also, if I remove the resumeBoostrap method and just do `angular.bootstrap` then the app works which tells me everything else is fine.

Here is my html file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <h1>AngularJS + RequireJS</h1>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div ng-view></div>

        <script data-main="main" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have spent quite some time on this one. The issue is caused by the lazy definition of the resumeBootstrap method. The angular.js detects dom ready via JQLite. When the document loads, it triggers a method which defines the resumeBootstrap method. The problem is that you cannot enforce processing order between domready and JQLite ready, if domready already fulfills your dependency before the method gets defined, you are in trouble.

The workaround is to enforce javascript to execute all event handlers before your resumeBootstrap invocation. I've used the setTimeout method to do so, e.g.: setTimeout(angular.resumeBootstrap, 0).

http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth#the-settimeout-func-0-trick

Hope it helped!

Comment: Dont you need to tell resumeBootstrap the name of your module such as `angular.resumeBoostrap(app['name')`. What you have will make the error go away, but does it load the proper base module?

Comment: No, resumeBootstrap() doesn't expect you to provide anything, it'll scan your html and attack your modules, controllers, etc. as usual. If you'd like to get rid of angular in your html, use the bootstrap method!~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

Comment: Okay cool. Using ngApp this will work, originally I was not using that. Actually now that I see it, if I just added ngApp to my index file it works without even having the setTimeout.

Answer (score 6):

According to [angular documentation for bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap):

> If window.name contains prefix NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP! when angular.bootstrap is called, the bootstrap process will be paused until angular.resumeBootstrap() is called.
>
> angular.resumeBootstrap() takes an optional array of modules that should be added to the original list of modules that the app was about to be bootstrapped with.

Here is my snippet to defer angular initializtion in requirejs application:

```
window.name = "NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!";

define(['angular', 'domReady', 'app'], function(ng, domReady){
    domReady(function(document){
        ng.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        ng.resumeBootstrap();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but i ran into this need for a (semi-)legacy application. Instead of using the `DOM Ready` event or any `settimeout()` shenanigans I checked the source code and found this **undocumented** feature: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1853

```js
if (isFunction(angular.resumeDeferredBootstrap)) {
    angular.resumeDeferredBootstrap();
}
```

This was added in this commit: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/c69caa7beee4e920f8f587eb3e943be99864a14f.
As this is undocumented you should use it at your own risk, but I doubt anything will change as angularjs has been in LTS for a while now.

This code will run if the bootstrap process was deferred and therefore be the perfect hook function to place your `angular.resumeBootstrap()` call in.

And example:

```js
angular.resumeDeferredBootstrap = function () {
    // perform actions that need to happen before bootstrapping here
    angular.resumeBootstrap();
    // you could also do some async work in here and make sure bootstrapping happens after
    someAsyncFunctionThatReturnsAPromise().then(function () {
        angular.resumeBootstrap();
    });
};
```